# CGAffineTransformScale modified after device rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I have a view that I am performing a transform on

```
originalTransform = self.appContainer.transform;
self.appContainer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.8, .8);
```

[image: Original Rotation]

If I do not rotate the device I can revert this back to the original by using

```
self.appContainer.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(originalTransform, 1, 1);
```

Unfortunately, if I rotate the device, the transformation matrix for the view gets modified by the view rotation and breaks the original scale. If I undo the scale after rotation I am left with the `UIView` not returning to its original full size.

[image: After Rotation]

[image: After Original Scale]

I'm sure that I need to make calculations between the original transformation matrix and the new one but I am unsure how to do this. The only thing I have been able to do to make this work is to revert the scale back to 1 before rotation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    self.appContainer.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(originalTransform, 1, 1);
}
```

And then rescale it with the newly modified transformation after the

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation               {
    self.appContainer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.8, .8);
}
```

This makes it work as I expect, but instead of going back to full screen, and then back to .8 scale, I'd like it to go from its new transformation to the correct .8 scale.

Comment: Have you finally handled this? I'm looking for solution.

Comment: I'm looking for solution too..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert it to original, try setting the transform to CGAffineTransformIdentity.

```
self.appContainer.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Comment: this doesn't work because the view's transformation is being modified by the device rotation event. By setting it back to identity I am getting the same results. After the device rotation event, the view's transformation needs to be taken to .8 scale of that orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove all autoresizing masks using.....

```
[self.appContainer setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
```